# Select label only if input is empty and not focused?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to select a `label` in CSS only when `input` has no `focus` and `value` is `''` (empty string)

```css
.email label:not(input[value='']:not(input:focus) ~ label) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='email'>
  <label for='email'>Email</label>
  <input type='email' id='email' value={email} onChange={handleEmail} />
</div>
```

Comment: Selecting a previous sibling in CSS is only possible with the pseudo class `:has()` which at time of writing is [only supported by Safari](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

Comment: @ZachJensz I am able to select previous sibling with above CSS, but I want to select it only when input input is not focused and value=''.

Comment: The subsequent sibling combinator cannot select **previous** siblings, only siblings that come after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a previous sibling in CSS is only possible with the [`:has()` pseudo class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) which at time of writing is [only supported by Safari](https://caniuse.com/css-has)

Your current selector:

```css
.email label:not(input[value='']:not(input:focus) ~ label)
```

Has syntactically incorrect parentheses, but if we fix that:

```css
.email label:not(input[value='']):not(input:focus) ~ label
```

It selects all labels that come after a label that is not an input with `value=''`, that is also not a focused input, which are all descendants of an element with class `.email`.

Here is how you would implement the selector you want with `has()`:

```css
label:has(+ #email:not(input[value='']:not(input:focus)) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div className='email'>
  <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
  <input type='email' id='email' value={email} onChange={handleEmail} />
</div>
```

[Here is a JavaScript polyfill](https://github.com/jplhomer/polyfill-css-has) that you might want to use in the meantime.

Other than that, one possible hack you could use that may or may not be terrible for screenreaders etc. is to reverse the markup and order it back with CSS:

```css
#email:not(input[value='']):not(input:focus)+label {
  color: green;
}

.email {
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='email'>
  <input type='email' id='email' value={email} onChange={handleEmail} />
  <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make life a little easier (since `:has` support is currently not so great). First, place the `input` *before* the `label` Then, to preserve your original formatting, declare your parent `email` div as a `flex` container and reverse its flex row direction.

**CSS**

```css
.email {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  column-gap: 0.35rem;
}

input[value=""]:not(:focus) + label {
  color: red;
}
```

**JSX**

```js
<div className="email">
  <input type="email" id="email" onChange={handleEmail} />
  <label htmlFor="email"> Email </label>
</div>
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-hypatia-r032kk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I think I beat you to this one :P do you know if it's bad for screen readers or not? I've heard changing the order through styling only is dangerous for certain applications

Comment: @ZachJensz Swapping the `label` and `input` positions results in perfectly semantic and valid `HTML`. Also, `label`s are not focusable (without `tabindex` changes) and would not pose a a screen-reader issue.