# Select pseudo element only if input is empty and not focused?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My question is similar to this: [Select label only if input is empty and not focused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023629/select-label-only-if-input-is-empty-and-not-focused)

But it's a bit more tricky because I need to select a pseudo-element of the input field if:

- input field is not focused
- something is in value

I have no access to the html. I came up with this but no matter what combination I try it's not selecting how I want it.

```
<input type="text" id="filter" value="lp">

.container input#filter:not([value=""]):not(input:focus)::before {
  content:'';  
}
```

Comment: Technically you cannot have a pseudo before or after element on an input element (though some browsers might support it). Can you alter the HTML? If so you could consider adding a label element. It would  help us give a useful answer if you could add enough to the code to show what you wanted the pseudo element to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` element is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) and as per the note on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

> The pseudo-elements generated by `::before` and `::after` are [contained by the element's formatting box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content), and thus don't apply to [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) such as `<img>`, or to `<br>` elements.

This means that no matter what you do, the `::before` pseudo-element will never show, even something as benign as:

```css
input::before {
  content: 'foo';
}
```

Will have no visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```css
input#filter:not(:placeholder-shown),
input#filter:not(:focus) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Also, don't forget to add a placeholder to all the inputs. You can do this with JS:

```js
let temp = document.querySelectorAll("input:not([placeholder]);
temp.forEach((ele)=>{ele.setAttribute("placeholder","text")})
```